# Angular Material DataTable Pagination undefined

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-5

Why mt pagination is not working

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

This is the same exaple which I copied from https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what is not working?

Comment: @S.H.N its working good]